# "error": "relation \"Issueds\" does not exist"

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to insert into a table I already have but sequelize is giving me an error with the table name changed
table name = Issued

```
{
    "status": 500,
    "error": "relation \"Issueds\" does not exist"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequelize pluralizes by default the table name.
Just enable `freezeTableName` at the model config object:

At your model definition:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Issued = sequelize.define(
    'Issued',
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        // Any other fields ...
    },
    {
        freezeTableName: true // This will prevent the name's pluralization.
    }
});
```